# Trigger Script Need Assistance

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script, google-sites

I am looking for assistance in setting up a script trigger specifically based on when a Google Site list page is updated. I can only find triggers based on changes in a spreadsheet not a google site.

Comment: That's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

IN your Google Spreadsheet you can Have a trigger with Google App Script or in your Google Spreadsheet

Example  for Google Spreadsheet :
http://railsware.com/blog/2013/09/16/useful-google-spreadsheet-script-triggers/

I hope this help can help you.